# Magento 1.9.2 create relation between customers and products

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create a relationship table between customers and products. The plan is that I will have a separate tab when editing customers to be able to assign products to that customers in a way like 'Related products' tab works when editing products.

So far I was able to add a tab to the admin but the big steps are in front of me. I would like to create a Many-to-many relationship table so I've added a file mysql4-install-0.1.0.php with the below:

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Create table 'customerproduct/product_relation'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('customerproduct/product_relation'))
    ->addColumn('customer_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Customer ID')
    ->addColumn('product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Product ID')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('customerproduct/product_relation',     array('product_id')),
        array('product_id'))
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('customerproduct/product_relation',     'product_id', 'customer/product', 'entity_id'),
        'product_id', $installer->getTable('catalog/product'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('customerproduct/product_relation',     'customer_id', 'customer/entity', 'entity_id'),
        'customer_id', $installer->getTable('customer/entity'), 'entity_id',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Customer Product Relation Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();

$installer->installEntities();
```

Not sure if the above is correct as at the moment it doesn't even get to this file. I would appreciate a little guidance on how to approach this and also how I can control saving the relationship. I've looked on the internet for similar solution but with no luck.

**EDIT 1:**
config.xml looks like the below:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Trike_Customerproduct>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Trike_Customerproduct>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customerproduct>
                    <file>trike_customerproduct.xml</file>
                </customerproduct>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customerproduct>
                <class>Trike_Customerproduct_Block</class>
            </customerproduct>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I've noticed that it doesn't appear in core_resource table. Version in the config is set to 0.1.0 and the installer is named mysql4-install-0.1.0.php and it's placed in the folder: sql > customerproduct_setup

Comment: The first problem to solve is why the setup file is not being accessed. How is it linked in your module's config.xml?

Comment: Try to remove appropriate row for this module from core_resources table. Maybe 0.1.0 version of Your's module was registred before You create install file. If it don't work paste config.xml of this module.

Answer (score 0):

Find a detailed answer below on how to make your **Install/Upgrade Script** work.

**Step 1:**

Create your module with the following files:

> app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/etc/config.xml
>
> app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Customerproduct.php
>
> app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Resource/Customerproduct.php
>
> app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Resource/Customerproduct/Collection.php
>
> app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>
> app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/sql/customerproduct_setup/install-1.0.0.php

**Step 2:**

Make sure below CONTENT is present in each of the files:

**app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Trike_Customerproduct>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Trike_Customerproduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customerproduct>
                <class>Trike_Customerproduct_Block</class>
            </customerproduct>
        </blocks>
        <models>            
            <customerproduct>
                <class>Trike_Customerproduct_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customerproduct_resource</resourceModel>
            </customerproduct>
            <customerproduct_resource>
                <class>Trike_Customerproduct_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <product_relation>
                        <table>customer_product_relation</table>
                    </product_relation>
                </entities>
            </customerproduct_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customerproduct_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Trike_Customerproduct</module>
                    <class>Trike_Customerproduct_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </customerproduct_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customerproduct>
                    <file>trike_customerproduct.xml</file>
                </customerproduct>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Customerproduct.php**

```
<?php
class Trike_Customerproduct_Model_Customerproduct extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
{   
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customerproduct/product_relation');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Resource/Customerproduct.php**

```
<?php
class Trike_Customerproduct_Model_Resource_Customerproduct extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customerproduct/product_relation','customer_id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Resource/Customerproduct/Collection.php**

```
<?php
class Trike_Customerproduct_Model_Resource_Customerproduct_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('customerproduct/product_relation');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/Model/Resource/Setup.php**

```
<?php
class Trike_Customerproduct_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup {}
```

**app/code/local/Trike/Customerproduct/sql/customerproduct_setup/install-1.0.0.php**

*I was able to find an issue with your Install Script code above. So I have updated your code and posting the file (without errors) here:*

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Create table 'customerproduct/product_relation'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('customerproduct/product_relation'))
    ->addColumn('customer_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Customer ID')
    ->addColumn('product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Product ID')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('customerproduct/product_relation',     array('product_id')),
        array('product_id'))
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('customerproduct/product_relation',     'product_id', 'catalog/product', 'entity_id'),
        'product_id', $installer->getTable('catalog/product'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('customerproduct/product_relation',     'customer_id', 'customer/entity', 'entity_id'),
        'customer_id', $installer->getTable('customer/entity'), 'entity_id',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Customer Product Relation Table');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();

$installer->installEntities();
```

I have tested this in my local machine and it works.

**Screenshot as below:**

[image]

[image]

Happy Coding...

Comment: That worked straight away, thank you Shivani.  
Now the next step for me is to figured out how to manage those while editing the customer details. I'm trying to get the idea from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product but few bits are already confusing as I'm struggling to find a template for that.